# C# SQL Insert Into issue

Tags: c#, sql, insert, insert-into

this is my insert into statement, but it's not working. I am getting an "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'"

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Notes (Notes, LastUpdatedBy, LastUpdatedTimeStamp)";
query += " VALUES (@Notes, @LastUpdatedBy, @LastUpdatedTimeStamp) WHERE PatID = '" + AccountNum.Text + "';";
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Well the *first* thing you should do is use parameterized SQL instead of building the SQL on the fly. Learn about SQL injection attacks, and how parameterized SQL prevents them.

Comment: You cannot use a `WHERE` clause with `VALUES`. You need to use `INSERT INTO tbl(...) SELECT .. FROM table WHERE`...

Comment: Yeah, what both of them said.  Read up on the two syntax variations of INSERT INTO [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp).  They can't be combined.

Comment: You're mixing up ```Insert``` and ```Update``` statement